# Getting PDF_VALIDATION_FAILED exception when trying to create envelopne in DocuSign sample recipe code

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to run the code available on [GitHub](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/test/Recipes/CoreRecipes.cs).

Issue is when I am trying to create an envelope I am getting an exception saying `"PDF_VALIDATION_FAILED"`.

Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Comment: Is the PDF provided a static PDF or is this an XFA PDF (dynamic/grows/shrinks/requires adobe reader to open)?

Comment: Hi @LuisScott, it was a static PDF. But it was corrupt, so I think that was it. I did have a few other questions I posted below. Can you please let me know if you have an idea about those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really you should be creating a new issue to log the new error you are getting, or modify your original post.  In any case the issue is most likely due to the file extension, the default is `pdf` so if you want to send a different format document you can do the following:

```
// Add a document to the envelope
Document doc = new Document();
doc.DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
doc.Name = Path.GetFileName("/PATH/TO/DOC/TEST.DOCX");
doc.DocumentId = "1";
doc.FileExtension = "docx";
```

Comment: Hi Ergin. Thanks a lot for the quick answer. It works when I change the file extension to "docx".

Comment: Great, can you please accept my answer in that case?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get a fix for this one. Apparently the file I was uploading was a corrupt file. However, not I am getting a different error 'UNABLE_TO_LOAD_DOCUMENT' when I try to upload a file in any format other than pdf.

Can anyone help me with this query? Also, what all file formats does DocuSign support?

Also, one of the previous libraries 'DocuSign.Integrations.Client' seem to work fine with word document uploads. Should they be used instead of 'DocuSign.eSign.Api', 'DocuSign.eSign.Client' and 'DocuSign.eSign.Model'?

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to the second error you mentioned:

I think you are missing assigning the FileExtension to the required format
something like : doc.FileExtension = "docx"

Once you do that, you will get rid of UNABLE_TO_LOAD_DOCUMENT error and the document can be sent successfully.