# upload a .docx or other supported fileformat to Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I understand that DocuSign has to translate, for legal reasons, different files to PDF,  and that's fine.  But I have a docx to start with. I do NOT want my client to have to "Export to PDF"  every time.

I can see from the DocuSign documentation that .doc and .docx are supported file formats, but when I try and create an envelope and send it, I get this back:

```
{
 "errorCode": "PDF_VALIDATION_FAILED",
 "message": "The validation of the PDF file failed."
}
```

Which makes sense as it's a .doc

Can I send a word doc to be signed via DocuSign?

Comment: Can you please share the code, JSON request which you are using to create an envelope. You can upload .doc or .docx directly in DocuSign.

Comment: Per the [official documentation](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-supported-file-formats), `.doc` and `.docx` are supported file formats.
Is your `docx` document password protected ?

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36626548/getting-pdf-validation-failed-exception-when-trying-to-create-envelopne-in-docus#36631287), did you assign the fileextension to `docx` ?

Comment: any idea how that would look in the JSON envenlope.  I assume the element name is not FileExcension.

Comment: See my answer below. Basically, I think the FileExtension element is required as DocuSign doesn't seem to be able to detect the file format. Though they could have done an effort of giving a more explicit error message instead of a "VALIDATION_FAILED"

Comment: That worked so I gave you a +1 and accepted your answer. Maybe you could do the same to my question...   But PDF  is the default.  You do not need to specify file-extension if the file is PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your JSON has the following elements and especially the `fileExtension` item. Below is what your JSON should look like :

```
"documents": [
        {
            "documentBase64": "FILE1_BASE64",
            "documentId": "1",
            "fileExtension": "docx",
            "name": "MyDocument.docx"
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

if still not work then you can add the following property

```
"documents": [
    {
        "documentBase64": "FILE1_BASE64",
        "documentId": "1",
        "include_metadata: true",
        "fileExtension": "docx",
        "name": "MyDocument.docx"
    }
```

According to DocuSign V2.1 "include_metadata: true" required it works after than my side